# Value passed with request.setAttribute() is not available by request.getParameter()

Tags: servlets, parameters, attributes, parameter-passing

I give a string variable a value in the normal execution of the code ,but if an exception happen I will give it another value , **the problem is that in catch block the value is still the same as i assign first** .

Here is my code ,first I assign page value "addUser" inside try block and in catch I give it "ErrorPage" value , I send the value of page within http request to forword method and inside it i print the value of page.
I cause an error in the excution of the code an i want it to go through catch block , and it does , but when it send the page value to the forword function the value of page is "addUser" not "ErrorPage" although i assign it to "ErrorPage" !!

```
String page = "addUser";

try {
    // ...

    request.setAttribute("page", page);
    forward(request, response);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    page = "ErrorPage";
    request.setAttribute("page", page);
    forward(request, response);
}
```

and here is the forword function

```
String page = request.getParameter("page");
System.out.println("page is " + page); // each time it prints addUSer
```

Can someone help? and thanx in advance.

Comment: Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself A lot can be eliminated already.

Comment: That won't compile.  You define `page` locally before the try block, and then redefine it again inside the try block.  That will give a compile error, so the code you gave us is useless to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @ Mark Peters-i rewrite my code here, My code is very large, i just give u a snapshot of the problem i got, but thanx for this note.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling `request.getParameter()` instead of `request.getAttribute()` to obtain the value. Since you've set it as request attribute, you should also get it as request attribute.

So:

```
request.setAttribute("foo", foo);
```

is only available by

```
Object foo = request.getAttribute("foo"); // NOT getParameter().
```

The `getParameter()` is only for HTTP request parameters as you can specify in request URL or in input fields of HTML forms.

Comment: @BalusC -  u r right, but i face another problem , that i use forward() method to handle both the  parameter "page" which send from jsp to servlet and attribute "page" from servlet to jsp and both to make forward to the intended page!!!when i make request.getAttribute() in forward method parameters form jsp are null.Is it a good idea to make 2 methods for forward() ?

Comment: No, just pass and access it as request attribute. Don't overcomplicate/duplicate things.

Comment: @BalusC - can we pass values form jsp to servlet as attribute?Since i will send values form input fields.

Comment: You can just access parameters as parameters. Attributes are available in JSP EL as `${page}`. I'd suggest to learn JSP/Servlet basics by a decent book/tutorial. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: @BalusC- the problem is that till now i use <%%> in jsp pages,but now I decide to learn JSTL and EL since there are a lot of facilities in JSTL.

Comment: Just do `request.getAttribute()` in *scriptlet* as well. It's no different from servlet code.

Comment: @BalusC- we r talking about different thing , in the previous comment i ask u how can i send values form jsp to servlets as attribute not how to get values from servlet to jsp !!

Comment: For JSP to Servlet, just send them the usual way by input fields. You don't need to change anything. They are available as request parameters. For Servlet to JSP, use request attributes. Once again, get through a decent JSP/Servlet tutorial to grasp the basic concepts.

Comment: @BalusC-  I solve the problem which makeing the same method to get parameters for jsp and get attributes from servlets , see what i had made :String page = (String)request.getAttribute("page");
             if(page==null)
                page = request.getParameter("page");

Comment: @BalusC - many many many thanks for your help and being sooooooo patient

Answer (score 0):

In addition to BalusC's point"

In your code you have declared two "String page" variable.  This will not compile.  I think the parameter that you are passing to the request in the catch must be the "other" page variable.  But it is hard to tell since this is not a true example.

Comment: This is in fact not an answer, but a comment. And, this has already been mentioned in a comment :)

Comment: Seeing, that the code he posted was not the actual code he was running, this could be part or the complete solution.  I started replying to this before any comments were in place and did not see Mark's comment.